# jQuery: prepending after the stuff

Tags: jquery

if i have

```
<div id="wallCommentResponse<?php echo $displayWall["id"]; ?>">
test
</div>
```

And:

```
 $('#wallCommentResponse' + wallID).prepend("lorem ipsum lorem ha!");
```

I want the prepended stuff come after the text inside it already and not before it..

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to [`Append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)?

```
$("#wallCommentResponse45").append("<b>foo</b>");
```

If that's not what you were after, perhaps edit your question to include an expected output.

Comment: @downvoter: care to explain how this answer doesn't help the asker? Sample code and all? These drive-by downvotes are not helpful to the community of people volunteering their time. This answer arguably has more value than other answers.

Comment: No problem, buddy :) Trolls, begone !